# Rounding to 2 decimal places in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, rounding

every time I want to round to 2 decimal places when it comes to zeros it doesnt want to round it...
how could I round it to 2 decimal places with zeros at the end which would give me 92.00 instead of just 92 ???

```
SELECT ROUND(COLUMN_NAME,2) FROM ....
```

it's giving me

```
COLUMN_NAME
92
```

but I want

```
COLUMN_NAME
92.00
```

I used TO_CHAR and it worked

```
ROUND(TO_CHAR(COLUMN_NAME),2)
```

thanks guys!

Comment: what is the data type of COLUMN_NAME?

Comment: What is the type of your column ?

Comment: Data type of COLUMN_NAME must be float[(<number>,<max_decimal_point>)]......

Comment: I had to convert it to TO_CHAR

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you may try the TO_CHAR function to convert the result

e.g.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(92, '99.99') AS RES FROM DUAL

SELECT TO_CHAR(92.258, '99.99') AS RES FROM DUAL
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This answer only allows up to 2 digits to the left of the decimal also. In the specific example provided by the OP there were only two decimal places; however for this answer to be more widely applicable it would be helpful it if solved for any number of digits to the left of the decimal and exactly two to the right. For example, if the data contained 123.456 or 1234567894.83748 etc.

Answer (score 10):

This works too. The below statement rounds to two decimal places.

SELECT ROUND(92.258,2) from dual;

Answer (score 8):

Try to avoid formatting in your query. You should return your data in a raw format and let the receiving application (e.g. a reporting service or end user app) do the formatting, i.e. rounding and so on.

Formatting the data in the server makes it harder (or even impossible) for you to further process your data. You usually want export the table or do some aggregation as well, like sum, average etc. As the numbers arrive as strings (varchar), there is usually no easy way to further process them. Some report designers will even refuse to offer the option to aggregate these 'numbers'.

Also, the end user will see the country specific formatting of the server instead of his own PC.

Also, consider rounding problems. If you round the values in the server and then still do some calculations (supposing the client is able to revert the number-strings back to a number), you will end up getting wrong results.

Comment: well said, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try using the COLUMN command with the FORMAT option for that:

```
COLUMN COLUMN_NAME FORMAT 99.99
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ....
```

Comment: wow great stuff...never heard of COLUMN COLUMN_NAME FORMAT! thanks

Comment: The mentioned rounding problems also apply to this solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(column_name,'99G999D99MI')
as format_column
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.