# Set Decimal places for number in Oracle

Tags: oracle, decimal

I have a query to get numbers from a table and I want to set two decimal places for numbers every time when selecting a value from a table.

For example:

```
30000 -> 300.00
1234567 -> 12345.67
```

Length of the number can be vary and doesn't contains any decimal places.

Sorry for bad grammar and I appreciate any advice you can give on this!

Comment: Divide the number by 100, and then try formatting using TO_Char() method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding to 2 decimal places in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720236/rounding-to-2-decimal-places-in-sql)

Comment: And, perhaps you can refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799151/always-show-decimal-places-in-sql

Comment: @ Am_I_Helpful 
I tried that but that method not work with every number (like 200000)

Comment: @ Am_I_Helpful & @  Kislay Kishore 

I used  TO_CHAR(AMOUNT/100, '9999999.99') and It works! 
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
select substr(('300000'),1,(select length('300000')-2 from dual))||'.'||substr('300000',-2) from dual
```

result 3000.00

```
select substr(('1234567'),1,(select length('1234567')-2 from dual))||'.'||substr('1234567',-2) from dual;
```

result 12345.67

Answer (score -1):

you may try with that

```
ROUND(TO_CHAR(COLUMN_NAME),2)
```

Comment: This will never give the expected result.